# Replace the value in textbox in ASP.NET webform if the value not exists in SQL Server table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a textbox on an ASP.NET web form with id of `txt_branch_name`.

I want to change the value in the textbox to `""` if the user enters a value that does not appear in a SQL Server table's column.

How can I do it in the `TextChanged` event?

```
protected void txt_branch_name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you are doing input validation. There are dedicated ways to do this. Usually ones that allow Autocompletion on the ClientSide. I am unsure if the Postback will raise the TextChanged event/what else might raise that Event. You really need to understand the PageLifecycle for this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: I have autocomplete on this field and I want to prevent client entered value that not appear in that list. i tried a lot of stuff but nothing helps

Comment: So you want to do a server side validation in case the Client Side one has a mistake and/or there is a race condition? Good idea. But again, look into the proper approachs to do validation in ASP.Net. It is a very common issue so there should be something. All I could find was the Validate function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validate.aspx). But to use it, you have to make your own derived class. There has go to be a better way then that.

Comment: A quick google serach found 3 articles on the mater: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972961.aspx | https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kh55542.aspx | https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you have a method in the page load, which would be setting the text box field.  So you would have to account for that with either a conditional, update panel, or another approach.  The reason the behavior your experiencing is the page load event will execute before the text box changed event actually fires.

```
if(!Page.IsPostback) 
{
     // Set your fields.
}
```

Otherwise you would need to use the update panel, which has logic you can find on Microsoft Developer Network or on Stack Overflow, I've got several answers about it under my profile.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I did it like this and it is work:

```
    protected void txt_branch_name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int BranchExist = 0;
        if (sqlcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlcon.Open();
        SqlCommand check_User_Name
     = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(* )  FROM [MASAB].[dbo].[Branchas_Of_Banks] NOLOCK where [Branch_Name_And_Code] ='" + txt_branch_name.Text+"'", sqlcon);
        BranchExist = (int)check_User_Name.ExecuteScalar();
        if (BranchExist == 0)
            txt_branch_name.Text = "";
```

Comment: That is less then ideal. You are opening a Disposeable resource (SQL Conenction) without properly disposing of it. More then that, it appaers you might actually share the same connection over multiple code pieces. Create, Use, Dispose in the same piece of code is the pattern I stick too. Usually using the using Statement. SqlConnection has some integrated connection pooling and it is better to not keep the connection around.

Comment: I will check for better solution. Thanks